# moving an object using Keydown Events

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move a box in the canvas, all the functions work fine, but as soon as i press down on any of the 4 keys the box disappears, I can tell it is because i have a ctx.ClearRect after pressing any of the 4 keys, i managed to stop it from dispersing, the problem is now it does not move or disappear and the cosole does not show any errors so I am stuck again.
any help would be really really helpful, thank you.

```
function Player (row,col) {
this.isUpKey = false;
this.isRightKey = false;
this.isDownKey = false;
this.isLeftKey = false;
this.row = row;
this.col = col;
this.color = "#f00";
}

var players = new Array();

function drawPlayer() {

    players[players.length] = new Player(2,2);

    for (var p = 0; p < players.length; p++) {
    ctxPlayer.fillStyle = players[p].color;
    ctxPlayer.fillRect(players[p].row*25, players[p].col*25, 25, 25);
    }
}

function doKeyDown(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        ClearPlayer();
        Player.isUpKey = true;
        Player.col = Player.col - 1;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        ClearPlayer();
        Player.isDownKey = true;
        Player.col = Player.col + 1;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        ClearPlayer();
        Player.isLeftKey = true;
        Player.row = Player.row - 1;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 68) {
        ClearPlayer();
        Player.isRightKey = true;
        Player.row = Player.row + 1;
    }
}
function ClearPlayer() {
    ctxPlayer.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
}
```

Comment: Can you create a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can investigate further?

Comment: Do you actually call `draw` again? The code looks like you just call clear.

Comment: @Rouby nothing happens when i try to call draw again, the event function works because i typed console.log("w") when w is down and it prints it on console.

Comment: @Danbopes the jsfiddle is not showing anything

Comment: Throw something together in the jsfiddle. Add the canvas, and javascript functions so I have something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a plnkr with an example of what I think you are trying to do:

```
// Code goes here

function Player(row, col) {
  this.isUpKey = false;
  this.isRightKey = false;
  this.isDownKey = false;
  this.isLeftKey = false;
  this.row = row;
  this.col = col;
  this.color = "#f00";
}

var players = [];
var ctxPlayer;
var currentPlayer;

window.onload = function()
{
  ctxPlayer = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
  currentPlayer = players[players.length] = new Player(2, 2);
  setInterval(render, 25);
}
window.onkeypress = doKeyDown;

function render()
{
  ClearPlayer();
  drawPlayer();
}

function drawPlayer() {


  for (var p = 0; p < players.length; p++) {
    ctxPlayer.fillStyle = players[p].color;
    ctxPlayer.fillRect(players[p].row * 25, players[p].col * 25, 25, 25);
  }
}

function doKeyDown(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.keyCode == 97) {
    currentPlayer.isUpKey = true;
    --currentPlayer.row;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 100) {
    currentPlayer.isDownKey = true;
    ++currentPlayer.row;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 119) {
    currentPlayer.isLeftKey = true;
    --currentPlayer.col;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 115) {
    currentPlayer.isRightKey = true;
    ++currentPlayer.col;
  }
}

function ClearPlayer() {
  ctxPlayer.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XejZKCkshNiihdy8ui1u?p=preview

First I introduced a `render` function to call clear and draw. This render function will get called every 25 ms after the window has loaded.

Then you created a new Player every draw-call. I changed it so that one player is created onload. The key-events are respective to this player-object.

Last I changed the key-events for my testing purposes, but they should work with yours too.

Keep in mind that the plnkr is just a quick example on how it works. You probably need to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i was looking for all night, very impressive, thank you  so much :)

Comment: Is there a reason to have to redraw every 25ms? Why can't we just redraw when something has changed?

Comment: You can redraw whenever you want. Like I said, the code is just some quick test-code I have written. Change as you need.

Comment: @Rouby sorry just a quick question, i want the player to be called after the player function starts in my code and not on load, how would you change that?

Comment: I have changed window.onload to a function called onload and called it from another function so when the canvas starts the game and a button is pressed it draws the player, the player only moves 1 space and does not clear the canvas, so this is another problem